# Reading C character arrays into doubles

Tags: c, string, cstring, scanf

This is a very elementary question, but my C is very very rusty and I need a refresher.  I have a string which is always in exactly the same format: `di ###.# ###.# ###`.

I would like to read the first number into `d1`, the second into `d2`, and the third into `d3`.

```
int main ()
{
  double d1, d2, d3;
  char mystring[] = "di 123.4 567.8 901";

  //some code that I don't know

  return 0;
}
```

Can you guys help me out?  I understand strtod() can help just parsing the numbers, but how do I skip over the "di" at the beginning?

Comment: Check if it helps http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/):

```
sscanf(mystring, "di %lf %lf %lf", &d1, &d2, &d3);
```

In this line, you are giving a format string (basically laying out where you expect the numbers to be), and then supplying the addresses of the variables you want the results to be put in, in order. The `&` operator takes the address of whatever it is applied to, which in this case is your `d1`,`d2`, and`d3` variables.

([The reference supplied](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) is on a C++ site, but is for this function)

Comment: `%L` is the format for `long double` - the OP's code is using `double`.  I think `%lf` is what you want here.

Comment: beat me to it, including the link to cplusplus.  +1.

Comment: @Carl: Ah yes, thanks. I just control-f'd for "double" in the reference. ;)